# Conservation of mass for fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My lecture notes contain the idea below, but I'm finding it difficult to understand one aspect.

---

Consider a finite volume $V$, bounded by a surface $S$ and outward pointing normal $\hat{\bf{n}}$.

A fluid occupies the space of which $V$ is a subset.

The fluid has velocity $u(\boldsymbol{r},t)$ and denisty $\rho(\boldsymbol{r},t)$.

By the principle of conservation of mass, we have that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_V \rho(\boldsymbol{r},t) \, dV=-\int_S \rho\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\, dS
$$

---

I understand that the left-hand side represents the rate of change of mass in $V$, and the right-hand side represents the rate at which mass flows *into* $V$ through $S$.

**I don't understand why these two quantities are equal though.**

Surely the rate of change of mass (i.e., the LHS) should be equal to the rate in **minus** the rate out? Rather than just the rate out.

Perhaps I have a fundamental misunderstanding of something here?

Comment: On the part of the boundary where $\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{n}} < 0$ we have mass flow in and where  $\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{n}} > 0$ we have mass flow out. Note that the outward pointing normal is used.

Comment: @RRL Thanks, I think that makes sense. So am I correct in thinking that the RHS represents the net mass flow? Moreover, why is the $-$ necessary on the RHS?

Comment: Yes -- it is the net mass flow rate.  The minus sign is necessary because if the dot product of the velocity and the outward normal at the surface is positive at a point then the fluid is leaving the region in a neighborhood of that point and we want the contribution to net flow to be negative.